# btleplug bluetooth periphals have local names missing

Tags: rust, bluetooth

I'm using the btleplug crate on Windows 11 to scan for peripherals and print out a list of devices' MAC address and names. For some reason, all names are missing. The code I'm using is:

```
use btleplug::api::{Central, Manager as _, Peripheral as _, ScanFilter};
use btleplug::platform::{Manager};
use std::error::Error;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let manager = Manager::new().await?;

    // get adapter
    let adapters = manager.adapters().await?;
    let central = adapters.into_iter().nth(0).unwrap();

    // start scanning for devices
    central.start_scan(ScanFilter::default()).await?;
    time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;

    // get a list of devices that have been discovered
    let devices = central.peripherals().await?;
    for device in devices {
        // print the address and name of each device
        let properties= device.properties()
            .await
            .unwrap()
            .unwrap();
        
        let names: Vec<String> = properties
            .local_name
            .iter()
            .map(|name| name.to_string())
            .collect();
        
        println!("{}: {:?}", device.address(), names);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

And the output I get is

```
6E:A4:49:71:1C:01: []
D3:81:93:EA:E4:B9: []
2C:76:79:7E:4B:72: []
E9:84:B3:82:CF:5A: []
25:DB:2D:F0:7B:5F: []
17:EB:FE:FD:1C:1B: []
...
```

The [example usage](https://docs.rs/btleplug/0.10.0/btleplug/#usage) in the docs use the `local_name` attribute assuming it exists, and I've followed that. How do I get the names to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Most Bluetooth LE devices that "advertise" their presence, however, do not transmit their "full local name" or "shortened local name". You can check this with various apps on your mobile phone, for example [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)

There are several reasons for this. On the one hand, the amount of information to be transmitted in the "advertisements" is severely limited and other data may be more important. On the other hand, such a unique name can pose a major privacy problem.